# How to save images to a new folder matlab

Tags: matlab

I need help with saving images to a new folder in matlab.

for example take the following code

```
timesteps=1000;

  for iii=1:timesteps
    ...
    ...
    image(somegraph);
    ...

    if mod(iii,10)==1
     print(sprintf('%s_%d','Graph at time',iii),'-dpng')
    end
  end
```

this loop excutes some code which produces a graph and the graph updates with every itteration, i print out and save every 10th itteration,

is there a way to save all these iterations into a new folder, and so that if I run the same code again, the folder is not overwritten but a new folder is written?

Thanks

Comment: You could save them into a folder called something like `'/MyProject/Run x/'` where `x` is replaced by the number of times you have run it. Then at the start of your code, have some code that checks what the highest "`x`" is in the all the folder names in the folder `'/MyProject/'` (i.e. you might have `'/Run 1/'` and `'/Run 2/'` already so it returns `2`), then creates a new folder `'/MyProject/Run MaxXPlus1/'` (i.e. `'/MyProject/Run 3/'`) in our example and then saves all your images to that new folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a folder according to the current date/time and storing the files there. So do something like

```
 foldername=datestr(now,'yyyy-mm-dd HH-MM-SS'); 
 mkdir(foldername);
 cd(foldername);
 % code to save the data here
 % ...
```

BTW, don't use colons for the timestamp in your foldername as some OSes don't like it as file/directory names.

Comment: This is not a very robust solution because it leave you in this new directory. If you insist on using `cd` you should at least ensure that at the end of your script you are in the original folder (even in case of an error). In general, it's better to provide an absolute path to `print` rather than changing directories for this reason.

Comment: Thanks Guys, Problem Solved!